# How to get the Start/End timings along with date and duration of query execution in a min/sec/micro sec for particular SQL_ID in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I want to know timings detail of a query for a particular SQL_ID. 
I'm trying to achieve this with below query, but it's not giving any output, even I tried with currently running and old sql_id:

```
select SID, SQL_EXEC_START, STATUS, SQL_ID, SQL_EXEC_ID, ELAPSED_TIME,
CPU_TIME, USER_IO_WAIT_TIME, APPLICATION_WAIT_TIME 
from V$SQL_MONITOR where SQL_ID='06gxhu1qvf0mk';
```

Comment: If the query takes less than 5 seconds, it won't show up in V$SQL_MONITOR. And after 1 minute, the stats might disappear. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28320/dynviews_3048.htm#REFRN30479

Comment: You might take a look at the DBMS_SQL_MONITOR package. You might be able to force your query to be monitored by putting it between BEGIN_OPERATION and END_OPERATION.

Comment: there's also a monitor hint to force a real time report to be available - note that these views access the Tuning Pack feature of Enterprise Edition of the database - not free